# Dynamic link on ChromeOS

Tags: android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, google-chrome-os

I am trying to open my application via Firebase Dynamic Link on ChromeOS, however it's not opening the application when I try to access it via Chromebrowser. Is there any way to make it work on ChromeOS, if not then would it be possible to implement this flow

> -> If application is not installed then redirect the user to Google Playstore.
>
> - After installing the application, user should get the deeplink, so that he would be redirected to the required place inside the
>   application.
>
> -> If application is installed then open the application.

Please help me to sort this out, let me know if there is any other tool that will be useful to implement deeplinks in ChromeOS. Thank you